# Serial communication with Arduino and serproxy to flash. Expected result just in test mode

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, serialization, arduino

I have an Arduino with three sensors connected. Every 100ms the arduino print a new line on serial with the three updated values separated by #:

Ex.:

> 23#11#50_18_1_14_48_0_226_0_16_33_64_2_1_97_36_128_24_170
>       26#12#50_18_1_14_48_0_226_0_16_33_64_2_1_97_36_128_24_170
>       33#11#50_18_1_14_48_0_226_0_16_33_64_2_1_97_36_128_24_170
>       48#10#50_18_1_14_48_0_226_0_16_33_64_2_1_97_36_128_24_170

Using serproxy to pass this values to Flash and the AS3 socket functions I can trace the serial output in test mode (CTRL+ENTER). At this point all works as expected.

When I publish and run the swf file I can receive the serial data but not as expected... Every 100ms I receive just part of the output. Not always the same part and not always the full expected output as I receive in test mode.

Could it be something related with security?

Here is my flash code to receive the data:

```
var dataSocket:Socket = new Socket("localhost",5333);
dataSocket.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, socketDataHandler);

function socketDataHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void {

        var sensValue:String;
        sensValue = dataSocket.readUTFBytes(dataSocket.bytesAvailable); 
        trace(sensValue);

        var sensData:Array = sensValue.split("#");
        sensor1 = sensData[0].toString();
        sensor2 = sensData[1].toString();
        sensor3 = sensData[2].toString();       
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running into Socket security errors that are bypassed when you re using debug mode.
Depending on what you need to do:
(1) If you want flash in the browser you will need to look into security http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7c60.html 
(2) or if you can use Air instead, you won't have to deal with any of this.

Comment: Hello mika, thanks for your help. I'me developing with Flash (AS3 not OOP). I need to run it on desktop not in a browser. Can I use Adobe Flash Professional to export an Air app using my fla project? To develop Air apps I need Flash Builder right?

Comment: And about the AS3 Security.APPLICATION?

Comment: You can create Air projects directly from Flash Pro - see: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS789ea67d3e73a8b21ec24feb12478b70aff-8000.html

Comment: Hello Mika. Now I'm working with air. The Security now is set to APPLICATION. But I can't get it to work. Now I have the same problem in Test mode (air).